# How to draw points of different colours in XCB

Tags: optimization, rust, rendering, x11, xcb

I'm trying to draw points on the window, using the `PolyPoint` XCB request.
Note that I'm using the crate "[xcb](https://crates.io/crates/xcb)" in Rust.

Here is my function :

```rust
fn set_pixels(&mut self, pixels: Vec<(usize, usize, u32)>) {
    self.connection.send_request(
        &x::PolyPoint {
            coordinate_mode: x::CoordMode::Origin,
            drawable: x::Drawable::Window(self.handle.unwrap()),
            gc: self.gc.unwrap(),
            points: pixels.into_iter().map(|(x, y, colour)| {
                x::Point {
                    x: x as i16,
                    y: y as i16,
                }
            })
            .collect::<Vec<x::Point>>().as_slice(),
        }
    );
}
```

At first, I'm not sure if this part is the easiest way to get a slice of `x::Point` from the vector :

```rust
pixels.into_iter().map(|(x, y, colour)| {
    x::Point {
        x: x as i16,
        y: y as i16,
    }
})
.collect::<Vec<x::Point>>().as_slice(),
```

Well, as we can see, we got a "colour" for each pixel, and I would like to use `x::PolyPoint` with a colour for each point I want to draw.

> I know I can use `ChangeGc` to set a drawing colour :
>
> ```rust
> self.connection.send_request(
>     &x::ChangeGc {
>         gc: self.gc.unwrap(),
>         value_list: &[
>             x::Gc::Foreground(/* hex colour */),
>         ],
>     }
> );
> ```
>
> But this would set the same colour for all the pixels.

How can I use "PolyPoint" to set pixels of different colours ? Without passing by a loop that would `ChangeGC` then just after use `PolyPoint` for one single pixel (this solution is too slow).

Earlier, I was doing a loop calling this function, to set pixels one by one. But this is too slow :

```rust
fn set_pixel(&mut self, x: usize, y: usize, hex_colour: u32) {
    self.connection.send_request(
        &x::ChangeGc {
            gc: self.gc.unwrap(),
            value_list: &[
                x::Gc::Foreground(hex_colour),
            ],
        }
    );

    self.connection.send_request(
        &x::PolyPoint {
            coordinate_mode: x::CoordMode::Origin,
            drawable: x::Drawable::Window(self.handle.unwrap()),
            gc: self.gc.unwrap(),
            points: &[
                x::Point {
                    x: x as i16,
                    y: y as i16,
                }
            ]
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: I just heard about `xcb_put_image`, would it be a good idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm now working with the double-buffering method.
A simple way is to draw on a `x::Pixmap` object, and then create an `update()` function for the window's structure :

```rust
/// Copies the `self.pixmap` area to the window.
fn update(&mut self) {
    self.connection.send_and_check_request(
        &x::CopyArea {
            src_drawable: x::Drawable::Pixmap(self.pixmap.unwrap()),
            dst_drawable: x::Drawable::Window(self.window.unwrap()),
            gc: self.gc.unwrap(),
            src_x: 0,
            src_y: 0,
            dst_x: 0,
            dst_y: 0,
            width: self.width as u16,
            height: self.height as u16,
        }
    )
    .expect("double buffering: unable to copy the buffer to the window");
}
```

Here is my `set_pixels` method (renamed to `draw_points` :

```rust
fn draw_points(&mut self, coordinates: &Vec<(isize, isize)>, colour: u32) {
    self.change_draw_colour(colour);

    // Creates an `x::Point` vector.
    let points = coordinates.into_iter().map(|coordinate: &(isize, isize)| {
        x::Point {
            x: coordinate.0 as i16,
            y: coordinate.1 as i16,
        }
    })
    .collect::<Vec<x::Point>>();

    self.connection.send_and_check_request(
        &x::PolyPoint {
            coordinate_mode: x::CoordMode::Origin,
            drawable: x::Drawable::Pixmap(self.pixmap.unwrap()),
            gc: self.gc.unwrap(),
            points: points.as_slice(),
        }
    )
    .expect("unable to draw points on the pixmap");
}
```

For external reasons that I won't go into, I'm not directly using a vector of `x::Point`, there is why I transform my `coordinates` value to a `Vec<x::Point`>.

For optimisation, I'm also saving the previous colour to avoid changing colour to the same colour :

```rust
fn change_draw_colour(&mut self, colour: u32) {
    if self.previous_colour == Some(colour) {
        return;
    }

    self.connection.send_and_check_request(
        &x::ChangeGc {
            gc: self.gc.unwrap(),
            value_list: &[
                x::Gc::Foreground(colour),
            ],
        }
    )
    .expect("unable to change the graphics context colour");

    self.previous_colour = Some(colour);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set different colors for a single drawing request in X11. I think this is not even possible with the RENDER extension. So, all the options you have are the ones you or others already mention.

Well, one more idea: If you usually have few different colors, you could group things by color. Your input seems to be `Vec<(usize, usize, u32)>`. You could transform this into a `HashMap<u32, Vec<(usize,usize)>>` and then use that to draw all pixels of a single color at once. Of course, this does not make sense if you expect few pixels of each color.

Comment: I thought about that too, but as you say it : it doesn't make sens if I expect few pixels of each colour.

Comment: I heard about xcb_put_image, would it be a good idea ?

Comment: I'm actually using a different way to use the HashMap in a smarter way. It's 10 times faster.
I still need to be faster, I will try other optimisations

Comment: This now feels a bit like an XY problem. Why do you need to set the colors of individual pixels anyway? Are you uploading an image? If so, PutImage might be a good idea. However, if you want certain parts unaffected, then that wouldn't work and you'd need to use RENDER's Composite request so that you can get "alpha stuff". Or perhaps SHM is the way to go so that you can just modify stuff locally? Please add some information about your use case

Comment: Actually, I'm creating a renderer. To print meshes, I perform triangles drawing, which performs lines drawing, which perform a `PolyPoint` request to draw points on the window.
All the points of the meshes are now saved in a `HashMap<Colour, Vec<Point>>`, and I perform a loop calling `set_pixels(points: Vec<Point>, colour: Colour)` for each colour.

But actually, to be faster I would like to print all the points, no matter the colour, like doing a `PolyPoint` request where every point of the array could have their own colour. But this is not possible.

Comment: Or perhaps I could give an array of pixels `Pixel { x, y, colour }`, and doing like a `xcb_copy_area` of that array of pixel to the window. I'm not sure about this, it can be the starting point of something, ...

Comment: Okay, that does indeed sound like you just want PutImage to upload an image.